# ASA5505 Sec topology setup

Tags: cisco-asa

I have ordered an ASA5505 sec appliance for my business network. I am replacing my SonicWall due to VPN tunnels dropping and to match my managed ISP provider that uses ASA5505’s. We need highly secure network to meet HIPAA compliance. My question is, do I need to have a router in-line with the ASA5505 or can I use the ASA5505 as my interface to both my VP tunnels and public internet via my switches?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The ASA 5505 can do NAT & Extended ACL's in addition to the VPN functionality you desire. There is no reason that the 5505 couldn't replace a basic SOHO router.

Just keep in mind the 3 VLAN limitation on a Base license 5505.

Answer (score 1):

The 5505 doesn't have any routing features beyond what the SonicWALL has (and vice versa), so if you need a router now, you'll almost certainly need a router with the 5505. At the same time, if you don't have a router now, you won't need to add one.